# How to check if a chrome app is installed in a different chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am wondering how I could check if a app is installed in chrome from a different chrome app. For example I have made app1 and app2 now I want to know if the user has app1 installed when he/she opens app2. Is this possible by some chrome api or is this not possible?

If I can not check if the user installed app1 then is their a work around of some sort?

I do have access to the chrome webstore if that matters.

What I want to do is provide some loyalty perks to those who install my other apps.

Comment: Why do you want this? We can't offer a workaround without knowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: So I can provide a sort of loyalty benefit to those who have my other app or apps installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you wrote both apps, it's pretty simple by using [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external):

In app1 background script:

```
var app2id = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoab2";
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  // This should fire even if the app is not running, as long as it is
  //   included in the event page (background script)
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(sender.id == app2id && request.areYouThere) sendResponse(true);
  }
);
```

Somewhere in app2:

```
var app1id = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoab1";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(app1id, {areYouThere: true},
  function(response) {
    if(response) {
      // Installed and responded
    } else {
      // Could not connect; not installed
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I like this answer but do both apps have to be run at the same time for this to work?

Comment: Hm. I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I know this is the case that once this listener is registered (in a background script), it will fire.

Comment: OK thanks answer has been excepted and thank you for the help it is much appreciated.

Comment: Tested it; I can confirm it will wake an inactive app.